# How to include different meta tags for each page dynamically within site to be seen in Google search

Tags: php, html, seo, meta, head

Need to include separate meta tags on each page so that each page can be listed below the main page in Google search.

For example, when we search "stack overflow" in google search, we can see 6 pages below 1 main page in search result.

As per my knowledge, we can do this easily by including  section for each page. But in my website, am using the include function of PHP  `<?php include 'header.php' ?>` to include my single header page, due to which my single set of meta tags are applied to all the pages instead of different ones for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for to achieve is site links, try looking at:
[Webmaster tools help - Sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en)

Comment: @Eden Feiles: Thank you very much for your quick response. I will surely go through it soon. :)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way for you is to setup one file that would be included in the header section and then

1) Set up associative array in the file, that has list of
[Page ID] => array([DESCRIPTION]=>CONTENT,[TITLE]=>CONTENT,[KEYWORDS]=>CONTENT);

2) Create few lines of code that read what page has been requested and pull appropriate [Page ID] data and fill required meta tags.

3) Echo the data, add it to template system or use it any way you need (in header.php) - can't tell more because you haven't provided any relevant code.

Comment: Thank you for the step by step answer :) I will try to develop the code as per your guidelines. Will let you know once done.